# Using a resize script to make my banner appear the same size as the window. Why is my banner giving issue when I forcibly make the browser smaller?

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize, banner

[My current development](http://scratchmediaohio.com/dev/index.php)

I only have the banner added at the moment, along with the scripts I needed. Every time I would resize the browser myself, the banner never follows like it should. I will be creating a fallback size for mobile but I wanted to fix this issue first. I am noticing that there could be issues with the script, but I'm not sure what.

Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function ($) {
 
ResizeImage();
 
 $(window).resize(function() {
 
 ResizeImage();
 });
 
});

function ResizeImage(){

 
 if ($('.bg').height() <= $(window).height()){
  
 if ($('.bg').height() == 0 || $('.bg').height() == undefined){
  $('.banner').css('height', $(window).height() - $(".banner").offset().top); 
 }else
 { 
 $('.banner').css('height', $('.bg').height() - $(".banner").offset().top);
 }
 }
 else
 {
 $('.banner').css('height', $(window).height() - $(".banner").offset().top);
 }
 

}
```

```css
body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

.banner {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden
}

.bg {
    background: url(../img/banner.png);
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #222;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat
}
```

```html
<div class="banner group">
    <div class="bg">
        <img src="img/banner.png" style="display: none;" alt="Scratch Media Delivers Explosive Design Options">
    </div>
</div><!--end banner-->
```

Comment: I'm confused. It looks okay to me. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm getting errors in the script and for example, if I open up the inspect tool, the banner cuts and I have to refresh for it to take up the window again.

Comment: Oh. You don't like how the hand slowly gets cut off the narrower the window becomes?

Comment: No, not that. I will have a mobile banner soon, I'm just getting the bearings in. For example if I have 'Inspect Element' open, and that fills up half the screen and I click off of the Inspect Element, [this happens](http://i.imgur.com/Lj07gZE.png). Same as if I resize the browser from the bottom. It doesn't snap to the bottom.

Comment: Interesting. So you always want the background-image to be as big as it can within the available viewport? ie, full size image or fill up window.

Comment: Yes, in fact my live site does this now with no issue, and I'm not sure what the problem is now. [link](http://www.scratchmediaohio.com)

Comment: Its because your live site is doing this with a css `background-image`, and your dev site is trying to hack it together with JS. Does that set you on the right path? Or would you like me to type up a more detailed answer below?

Comment: I think I actually fixed it. I needed to put an absolute positioning on the class itself. It was buried in my old minified css.

Answer (score 0):

Use css instead.

```
position:fixed;
left:0px;
top:0px;
width:100%;
height:100%;
```

apply it to the image

Comment: When I do that it covers everything since the fixed position follows. I was going to have more content go after the banner.